# LinkedHashMap from gson returns JsonSyntaxException from shared preferences

Tags: android, json

I am saving a LinkedHashMap in shared preferences as a JSON like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<Date, Integer> todayHistoryMap = SharedPreferencesManager.getHistoryWeekPointsMap(context);

Date dateCalled = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L);

int pointsForTodayThisWeek = 6;


todayHistoryMap.put(dateCalled, pointsForTodayThisWeek);

final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String hashMapString = gson.toJson(todayHistoryMap);

editor.putString(JSON_WEEK_HISTORY_POINTS, hashMapString);

Log.d(TAG, "week points history saved: " + hashMapString);

editor.apply();
```

Now I retrieve it like this:

```
String storedHashMapString = getSharedPreferences(context).getString(JSON_WEEK_HISTORY_POINTS, "none");

Type type = new TypeToken<LinkedHashMap<Date, Integer>>() {
}.getType();

Gson gson = new Gson();

if (!storedHashMapString.equals("none")) {
    try {
        LinkedHashMap<Date, Integer> weekPointsHistoryMap = gson.fromJson(storedHashMapString, type);
        return weekPointsHistoryMap;
    } catch (IllegalStateException | JsonSyntaxException exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Json error" + exception);
        return null;
    }
} else return new LinkedHashMap<Date, Integer>();
```

Here is an example of the JSON:
{"Sun Dec 31 23:25:01 GMT+02:00 2017":1}

Now it always throws a JsonSyntaxException. I don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: Please, add example of `JSON`

Comment: Added example...

Comment: If you're using dates as keys, then why do you use a LinkedHashMap? Why not just order chronologically with a TreeMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `Gson` don't know which date [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you use to store date string. Date format for your `JSON` example is:

> "EE MMM d H:m:ss zz y"

When you create `Gson` object for parsing `JSON` from `String`, you should set Date format.
Use this code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("EE MMM d H:m:ss zz y").create();
```

Instead of this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Try to change it in both methods.

Comment: I have tried this, but I'm still getting this message: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["Mon Jan 01 21:04:13 GMT+02:00 2018']: Invalid number: Mon

Comment: I did that. But should I do it when I save the JSON or just when I retrieve it?

Comment: Try to use it in both methods

Comment: Now I don't get a JsonSyntaxException but its not calling the line LinkedHashMap<Date, Integer> weekPointsHistoryMap = gson.fromJson(storedHashMapString, type); It just jumps out of the try loop.

Comment: Does this mean anything? serializeNulls:falsefactories

Comment: Maybe, you didn't call method to store `JSON` and `storedHashMapString` is `"none"`?

Comment: @RJB, please post what contains in `dateCalled` and `pointsForTodayThisWeek` variables